# Boost::spirit::qi - How do I build a parse rule that sets a property?

Tags: c++11, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'd like to build a rule that takes in a few parameters from a parsed line then sets a few as constant. Is that possible? An (invalid) example to illustrate what I'm trying to do is below. I think I'm using `_r1` incorrectly here, but I'm not sure how to get at the right thing. Assume I don't want to just modify `r` before sending it into the parser.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_plus.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_sequence.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_string.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_object.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/bind/bind_function.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
struct Sample
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Sample, a , b)

const rule<std::string::const_iterator, Sample()> AnythingAndOne = int_ >> eps[_r1.b = 1] >> eoi;


int main()
{
    std::string z("3");
    Sample r;
    parse(z.begin(), z.end(), AnythingAndOne, r);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `_r1` is a placeholder for an [inherited attribute](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/abstracts/attributes/nonterminal_attributes.html). You don't declare any inherited attribute. What did you mean here?

Comment: I meant to parse one int, then set the other int to a constant value (one in this case). So I'd get back Sample a = {3,1} from "3".

Comment: Can you do that by adding a fixed int to the tuple in the rule?

Comment: Sure. I'd be a lot simpler. Thanks clarifying. Posting in a few minutes

Comment: Thanks man, you've really helped out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, with reference to [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil) I'd avoid the semantic action.

You can directly synthesize a particular attribute value by using `qi::attr`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/302ed08997496f49)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>

struct Sample {
    int a;
    int b;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Sample, a , b)

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    std::string const z("3");
    Sample r;
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, Sample()> AnythingAndOne
         = qi::int_ >> qi::attr(1) >> qi::eoi;

    if (parse(z.begin(), z.end(), AnythingAndOne, r))
        std::cout << "Parsed: " << boost::fusion::as_vector(r) << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed: (3 1)
```

Comment: Perfect. This solves what I was getting at. I don't expect to use it, but just so I know how, how do you do it with a semantic action?

Comment: (The non-semantic action version will go in the prod code, obviously)

Comment: For fun, a more complicated example: [showing how you can achieve quite complex logic without actions](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b501825f851deecc). With semantic actions, the regular place holder `qi::_1` refers to the subject parser, `qi::val` refers to the declared attribute, and all actions need to be deferred actors, e.g. [this equivalent demo using semantic actions](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f37a307e2d847c5)

Comment: Oh yeah, no I'm quite aware of the games you can play with ors in parsers. That's why I love this kind of stuff.

Comment: OHHHHH USING THE NAMESPACE Now I get it.

Comment: I was distracted earlier, noting I forgot about [using `operator%=`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/nonterminal/rule.html#spirit.qi.reference.nonterminal.rule.expression_semantics) in the presence of semantic actions: [better now](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c28d18c424d776ce) - sorry for the delay